# How to export and integrate an independent Angular module through symlink or repository?

Tags: angular, centos

Dependencies:

- Angular 8.1.2
- Node v10.16.0
- NPM 6.10.2
- Centos 7

I want to be able to create an Angular application integrating different independent modules. These modules will be present on a private repository. Therefore they will have a version and can be added in a package.json.

These modules will contain tests, components, templates, and services.

According to the documentation of angular, it is possible to do what I wish with the creation of a library -> https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

However, it is only possible to generate a library inside an Angular application and I do not want to do that. My wish is to have an independent module that is only added as a dependency in the package.json or with a symlink.

Also, I saw that it was possible to create a full angular application and export it as a repository. However, I find it a bit "heavy". I only want to be able to export a module that will contain very few services or components. I do not need it to be an entire angular application!

Here is what I realized for the moment:

1. Creating a library called module-a in the main angular application
2. Moved the module-a library to a folder outside the main angular application
3. I link this library with "npm link"
4. I added the module-a library in the main application with "npm link module-a".

> However this solution is not viable because when I make a "ng generate library" there is a strong dependence with the parent. We can not export it.

1. I created a full angular application containing the module-a.
2. I link this angular application with "npm link"
3. I added this angular module-a application in the main application with "npm link module-a".

My IDE does not recognize module-a when I try to import it into the main application. In addition, I find this method very heavy because the module-a is an entire angular application that will contain only a few components and services.

The JSON package of my main application

```
{
  "name": "pui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

The result I would like is to be able to export a module as a repository. This module must be light and inherit the package.json dependencies from the main angular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a standalone library, this link will maybe help you https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10929

Or you can use this option when you create a new angular app:  ng new  --create-application false

Then you can use ng generate library

Comment: Thank you! This option looks great and simple. I will use this one :)